# не получается заменить пробел при помощи replace Python

Tags: python, replace

```
s_2=' '
s=str('НУЖНО ЛЮБИТЬ МАТЕМАТИКУ')
def count_word(s):
    kol=0
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
      if s[i]==s_2:
        s[i].replace(' ','')   
      kol+=1
    print('В словосочетании:{} {} буквы'.format(s,kol))
count_word(s)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неправильно применяете replace.

> Метод str.replace возвращает копию строки, в которой заменены все
>   вхождения указанной строки указанным значением.

```
s = 'НУЖНО ЛЮБИТЬ МАТЕМАТИКУ'
def count_word(s): 
    s = s.replace(' ','')    
    print('В словосочетании:{} {} буквы'.format(s,len(s)))
count_word(s)
```